# Rotate Background Image of Body by Time

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me make a simple javascript to get element body so I can alternate its style to change background images every X seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a function to switch backgrounds and add an interval to do it.
Backgrounds are contained in array **bgArr**.

```
bgArr = ['images/bg1.jpg', 'anotherdir/bg2.jpg', 'otherone/bg3.jpg'];
bgCur = 0;
backgroundSwitch = function()
{
    if (bgCur == bgArr.length) bgCur = 0;
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+ bgArr[bgCur++]+ ')';
}
window.setInterval(backgroundSwitch, 30000); // Switch every 30 seconds.
```

Comment: It switches, but it just doesn't continue to rotate through the images. Would this be resolved if I made an array? And how do I make an array in javascript? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are three things you'll need (two of which have been mentioned by other answers):

1. The builtin function `setInterval()`, to fire off a handler function every X seconds.
2. The expression `document.body`, which gets you a direct reference to the DOM object for the `body` element.
3. A function (to be passed to `setInterval()`) which will switch between images. This will probably require some data structure to remember the list of images to switch between.

For example:

```
var images = ['./image1.jpg', './image2.jpg'];
var curImage = 0;
function switchImage()
{
    curImage = (curImage + 1) % images.length
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[curImage] + ')'
}
window.setInterval(switchImage, numSeconds * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

check out [**setInterval**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval)

```
setInterval(function () {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = new_image;
}, 3000);
```